# SSRS Excel Renderder, set up page break vertically in single sheet for printing rather than new tab

Tags: excel, printing, reporting-services

I have two tables in my ssrs report, I want to export those two tables in single sheet of excel but with page break so that if I do print preview, two different tables should be displyed in two different pages, even if first page has enough space to display the second table. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please suggest me whether it is possible or not from SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, **this is not possible** with the default renderers. Either there *is* a page break between the two tables, or there *isn't*, the report itself has no knowledge of how it will be rendered. Excel will always generate a new tab for a page break, afaik.

See the [corresponding msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255244.aspx?ppud=4) for more info on (amongst other things) page breaks.

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to be the case. I guess the only way to enforce the page breaks within a single worksheet would be to write a separate macro?

Answer (score 0):

If your two data sets have the same structure, you might be able to accomplish this by doing a union of both queries. Just add a column to identify each data set, then page-break on the new column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can make it. Select the table you set pagebreak. Then press F4 to see its properties. Then you can find "Disabled" under PageBreak tag. Use expression:

```
=Iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML" Or Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False)
```

Then export it in Excel and it won't be separated into 2 pages.